# Functional inequality

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f, g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$  be bounded functions satisfying
$$
|f(x+y)-f(x)g(y)|\le \frac 1 4
$$
for all $x, y\in \Bbb R$.

Prove or disprove 
$$
|f(x)||1-g(y)|\le \frac 1 4
$$
for all $x, y\in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not generally true. Counterexample: Take $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}4$ and $g(x)=\cos x$.

Then,
$$\left|f(x+y)-f(x)g(y)\right|=\frac14\left|\sin(x+y)-\sin x\cos y\right|=
\frac14\left|\sin y\cos x\right|\le \frac14$$
while for $x=\frac{\pi}2$ and $y=\pi$:
$$\left|f(\frac{\pi}2)\right|\left|1-g(\pi)\right|=\left|\frac{1}4\right|\left|2\right|=\frac12> \frac14$$